# Jackson JsonMappingException START_ARRAY error - when json having nested same node

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize below json. My json contains same node nested two times. As you can see the same **image** node is repeated twice.

```
{
    "error": null,
    "feed": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "message": "Hello World!",
            "image": {
                "url": "http://localhost:8888/hello/media/55ebe591ee42d.jpg",
                "width": "970",
                "height": "485"
            }
            "created_at": "2015-09-06 12:34:50",
            "updated_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "profile": {
                "id": "10",
                "name": "Mr X",
                "image": {
                    "url": "http://localhost:8888/instagram-rest/uploads/profile/55ffa473a1853.jpg",
                    "width": "640",
                    "height": "640"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Below are my classes required to deserialize the json.

**Image.java**

```
public class Image {
    private String url;
    int width, height;

    public Image() {
    }

    public Image(String url, int width, int height) {
        this.url = url;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    /** setter/getters **/
}
```

**Profile.java**

```
public class Profile {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("image")
    private Image image;


    /** setter/getters **/
}
```

**Feed.java**

```
public class Feed {

    @JsonIgnore
    private String id;

    private String message, created_at, updated_at;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String feed_id;

    private int comments_count, likes_count;

    @JsonProperty("image")
    private Image image;

    @JsonProperty("profile")
    private Profile profile;

    /** setter/getters **/    
}
```

**FeedResponse.java**

```
public class FeedResponse extends BaseResponse {
    @JsonProperty("feed")
    private List<Feed> feed;

    public List<Feed> getFeed() {
        return feed;
    }

    public void setFeed(List<Feed> feed) {
        this.feed = feed;
    }
}
```

And to parse the json I used below code

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
FeedResponse res = objectMapper.readValue(response, FeedResponse.class);
```

While parsing if I remove **image** from **Profile.java** everything is working fine. Otherwise I am getting below error.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of model.Image out of START_ARRAY token
```

Any help will be much appreciate.

Thank you

Comment: There is a missing comma in the JSON after the the image's closing bracket. Is that the cause of the error?
You can use a tool like http://jsonlint.com/ to check if a JSON is correct.

Comment: @Raimundo No the json is correct. I missed the comma while posting here.

Comment: I tried your code in my computer and it worked fine. However I had to modify the FeedResponse class to remove the BaseResponse extends.
You didn't post the code of the BaseResponse class, and you should. Does this class contains an image property?

Comment: @Raimundo No, it contains a error string variable. Nothing else.